# Removing duplicate columns in table when there are more than one duplicate set of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I see how to handle the case of removing duplicate columns when there are only two blocks of duplicates, but in my real data I have 3 or more. I've tried to come up with some toy example data sets where there is an extra duplicate set of column names which I would like to collapse. Is there a similarly straightforward way of untangling these messes with `dplyr` and `tidyr`?

Easier case:

```
structure(list(x = c("a", "a", NA, "a", "a", NA, "a"), y = c(1, 
5, NA, 15, 19, NA, 27), z = c(2, 6, NA, 16, 20, NA, 28), x.1 = c("b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), y.1 = c(3, 7, 11, 17, 21, 23, 
29), z.1 = c(4, 8, 12, 18, 22, 24, 30), x.2 = c(NA, NA, "a", 
NA, NA, "a", NA), y.2 = c(NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 25, NA), z.2 = c(NA, 
NA, 14, NA, NA, 26, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "x.1", "y.1", 
"z.1", "x.2", "y.2", "z.2"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

This looks like in R:

```
     x  y  z x.1 y.1 z.1  x.2 y.2 z.2
1    a  1  2   b   3   4 <NA>  NA  NA
2    a  5  6   b   7   8 <NA>  NA  NA
3 <NA> NA NA   b  11  12    a  13  14
4    a 15 16   b  17  18 <NA>  NA  NA
5    a 19 20   b  21  22 <NA>  NA  NA
6 <NA> NA NA   b  23  24    a  25  26
7    a 27 28   b  29  30 <NA>  NA  NA
```

How it should look after `dplyr`:

```
  x  y  z x.1 y.1 z.1
1 a  1  2   b   3   4
2 a  5  6   b   7   8
3 a 13 14   b  11  12
4 a 15 16   b  17  18
5 a 19 20   b  21  22
6 a 25 26   b  23  24
7 a 27 28   b  29  30
```

Harder case:

```
structure(list(x = c("a", "b", NA, "a", "a", NA, "a"), y = c(1, 
7, 9, 15, 19, NA, 27), z = c(2, 8, 10, 16, 20, NA, 28), x.1 = c("b", 
NA, "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), y.1 = c(3, NA, 11, 17, 21, 23, 
29), z.1 = c(4, NA, 12, 18, 22, 24, 30), x.2 = c(NA, "a", "a", 
NA, NA, "a", NA), y.2 = c(NA, 5, 13, NA, NA, 25, NA), z.2 = c(NA, 
6, 14, NA, NA, 26, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "x.1", "y.1", 
"z.1", "x.2", "y.2", "z.2"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

This looks like in R:

```
     x  y  z  x.1 y.1 z.1  x.2 y.2 z.2
1    a  1  2    b   3   4 <NA>  NA  NA
2    b  7  8 <NA>  NA  NA    a   5   6
3 <NA>  9 10    b  11  12    a  13  14
4    a 15 16    b  17  18 <NA>  NA  NA
5    a 19 20    b  21  22 <NA>  NA  NA
6 <NA> NA NA    b  23  24    a  25  26
7    a 27 28    b  29  30 <NA>  NA  NA
```

What it should like after `dplyr`:

```
  x  y  z x.1 y.1 z.1
1 a  1  2   b   3   4
2 a  5  6   b   7   8
3 a 13 14   b  11  12
4 a 15 16   b  17  18
5 a 19 20   b  21  22
6 a 25 26   b  23  24
7 a 27 28   b  29  30
```

In both cases the output data frame should have two columns with a first and b second.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: good point. updated. I'd probably also prefer to append or prepend the unique result of the x column into the column names of y and z.

Comment: For the hard case, the first column also has 'b', which got replaced in the expected.  Is it a typo?

Comment: no, the extra challenge for the hard case is that the column order of my inputs is not guaranteed, but I'd like my output order to be.

Comment: seems really hard :-)

Comment: the values in x are at least guaranteed to be "a" or "b"

Comment: Suppose you have 4 sets of duplicates, then do you have sets of 3 columns in the expected ?

Comment: First case is very easy: `df[is.na(df$x), c("x", "y", "z")] <- df[is.na(df$x), c("x.2", "y.2", "z.2")] ; df[1:6]`

Comment: @akrun: yes, and the real data set has 5 sets of duplicates with 4 columns expected.

Comment: @wdkrnls can't you generalize my solution? It should be both easy and very fast for computational point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases are just simple indexing problems

---

Fist case (the easy one)

```
indx <- is.na(df$x)
df[indx, 1:3] <- df[indx, 7:9]
df[1:6]
#   x  y  z x.1 y.1 z.1
# 1 a  1  2   b   3   4
# 2 a  5  6   b   7   8
# 3 a 13 14   b  11  12
# 4 a 15 16   b  17  18
# 5 a 19 20   b  21  22
# 6 a 25 26   b  23  24
# 7 a 27 28   b  29  30
```

---

Second case (the harder one)

```
indx <- 1:3
indx2 <- as.logical(rowSums(is.na(df2[indx + 3])))
indx3 <- as.logical(rowSums(is.na(df2[indx])))

df2[indx2, indx + 3] <- df2[indx2, indx]
df2[indx3, indx] <- df2[indx3, indx + 6]
df2[1:6]
#   x  y  z x.1 y.1 z.1
# 1 a  1  2   b   3   4
# 2 b  7  8   b   7   8
# 3 a 13 14   b  11  12
# 4 a 15 16   b  17  18
# 5 a 19 20   b  21  22
# 6 a 25 26   b  23  24
# 7 a 27 28   b  29  30
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as a static correcting but depending on number of duplicates you can turn this into a function to make it more dynamic.

```
library(stringr)
# Method One (Works when you have true duplicates from some join methods)
for(i in 1:length(df))
{
  Cols = which(colnames(df)==colnames(df)[i])
  if(length(Cols)>1){
    df[Cols[1]] = NULL 
  }
}


# Method Two 
for(i in 1:length(df))
{

Val = which(strsplit(colnames(df)[i], "")[[1]]==".")
if(length(Val) >= 1 ){

  Cols = which(colnames(df)==paste(substr(colnames(df)[i],1,Val-1),".2",sep=''))

    df[Cols[1]] = NULL 
   }

}
```